# Qt QGraphicsItemGroup get coordinate of transformed items

Tags: c++, qt

I have many rectItem in a

```
QVector <GraphicsRectItem *> list_rect_item;
```

I group them in a QGraphicsItemGroup to make them rotate from the middle of my scene :

```
for(int i=0 ; i < list_rect_item.size() ; i++) {
    group->addToGroup(list_rect_item.at(i));
}

QPoint point_center(scene.width()/2, scene.height()/2);
group->setTransformOriginPoint(point_center);
group->setRotation(ui->box_angle->value());
```

But now I want to know there new coordinate so I try this but it didn't work (I get the coordinate BEFORE the rotation) :

```
QList<QGraphicsItem> group_list = group->childItems();

for(int i=0 ; i < list_rect_item.size() ; i++) {
    list_rect_item.at(i)->setPos(group_list.at(i).pos());
    scene.addItem(list_rect_item.at(i));
}
```

How can I transform a group of items, and after get all of there new coordinate ?
(After the transformation I want to continue to use them not as a group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call *scenePos()* function to get the global coordinate of the item after the transformation. Calling *pos()* function will give you the local coordinate of the item with respect to the parent of the item.

Answer (score 0):

To ungroup an item group, you can either call QGraphicsScene::destroyItemGroup(), or you can manually remove all items from the group by calling removeFromGroup().

So after grouping and applying transformations you can ungroup it by:

```
scene.destroyItemGroup(group);
```

Also the Qt Documentation states that:

> The operation of adding and removing items preserves the items'
>   scene-relative position and transformation, as opposed to calling
>   setParentItem(), where only the child item's parent-relative position
>   and transformation are kept.

So after ungrouping you can easily get the position or other properties of the items and continue your desired transformations or actions.